# Could this question be asked on Mathematics?

Tags: discussion

Could [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678305/converting-a-2d-array-of-2d-arrays-into-a-single-2d-array#24678305) be asked here? It is the kind of question that requires knowledge about matrices much more than specifically about coding.

Comment: If you can extract an actual mathematical question from beneath all that code, then yes. In the present form, no.

Comment: Look at your question, matrices is the wrong tool for this problem. It will be easier if you visualize the big matrix as a big square of pixels. You cut your big square into multiple vertical and horizontal strips of unequal widths and the problem you have is fitting a smaller square into each of the cells formed by the intersection of horizontal and vertical strips. The width of a strip is the maximum of the width of the small squares it contain. The $x$-offset of a vertical strip is the sum of the width of vertical strips on its left. Same things happen to horizontal strips.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a math question (as of now), and thus would not be welcome here.  Knowledge of matrices is much different than what you are discussing in that question.